# Load different sweep files in Hydra multirun

Tags: fb-hydra

```
├── configs
│   ├── default.yaml
│   └── agent
│       └── agent_A.yaml
│   └── experiment
│       └── long.yaml
│       └── short.yaml
│   └── environment
│       └── easy.yaml
│       └── hard.yaml
│   └── hydra
│       └── launcher
│           └── cluster_X.yaml
│           └── cluster_Y.yaml
```

I need to perform different sweeps. Right now, I do it by adding the following config to `default.yaml`

```
hydra:
  sweeper:
    params:
      environment: easy
      experiment: short
      experiment.rng_seed: range(0, 10)
      agent.lr: 1e-3, 1e-2, 1e-1
      agent.size: 64, 128, 256
```

My problem is that I need to edit the file every time I need to run a sweep because the combinations I need to run are:

- environment easy / experiment short
- environment hard / experiment long
  And I may also want to sweep over a different range of `agent.lr` and `agent.size` depending on the sweep.

I run my code with

```
python main.py -m hydra/launcher=cluster_X
```

and I would like to add something like

```
python main.py -m hydra/launcher=cluster_X  hydra/sweeper=sweep_1
```

where `sweep_1.yaml` is in `hydra/sweeper` and is a config file with the details of the sweep. Then I'd have many `sweep_1`, `sweep_2`, ... files for whatever I need to run, not having to edit `default.yaml` every time.

I tried making `sweep_1.yaml` like this

```
# @package hydra.sweeper
params:
  environment: easy
  experiment: short
  experiment.rng_seed: range(0, 100)
  agent.lr: 0.1, 1
```

but I don't know what `_target_` use.
I am not even sure this is the right way to do what I need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing my sweeper YAML files to something like this I can do exactly what I wanted to.

```
# @package _global_
# @package hydra.sweeper
_target_: hydra._internal.core_plugins.basic_sweeper.BasicSweeper
max_batch_size: null
params:
  environment: easy
  experiment: short
  experiment.rng_seed: range(0, 100)
  agent.lr: 0.1, 1
```

This uses the default sweeper. `max_batch_size` is mandatory. .